# Define custom array-like object with numeric access

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I define a collection object in JavaScript that behaves like an array in that it provides access to its items through the numeric index operator? I'd like to allow this code:

```js
// Create new object, already done
let collection = new MyCollection();

// Add items, already done
collection.append("a");
collection.append("b");

// Get number of items, already done
console.log(collection.length);   // -> 2

// Access first item - how to implement?
console.log(collection[0]);   // -> "a"
```

My collection class looks like this (only part of the code shown):

```js
function MyCollection(array) {
    // Create new array if none was passed
    if (!array)
        array = [];
    this.array = array;
}

// Define iterator to support for/of loops over the array
MyCollection.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function () {
    const array = this.array;
    let position = -1;
    let isDone = false;
    return {
        next: () => {
            position++;
            if (position >= array.length)
                isDone = true;
            return { done: isDone, value: array[position] };
        }
    };
};

// Gets the number of items in the array.
Object.defineProperty(MyCollection.prototype, "length", {
    get: function () {
        return this.array.length;
    }
});

// Adds an item to the end of the array.
MyCollection.prototype.append = function (item) {
    this.array.push(item);
};
```

I think jQuery supports this index access, for example, but I can't find the relevant part in their code.

Comment: Suggestion: use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: Object.defineProperty maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Your class can extend Array: `class MyCollection extends Array {...}` - you no longer need the internal array property, the iterator, or the custom `length` property, and you can define arbitrary methods like `append` which would simply call `this.push(item);`.

Edit: if you can't use the `class` keyword, you can do it the old school way:

```
// note - this is no different than doing class MyCollection extends Array {}
function MyCollection() { }
MyCollection.prototype = new Array();
MyCollection.prototype.constructor = MyCollection;
```

Or you can use [JavaScript Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) so that any time someone tries to read a property you can return the value they're looking for. This shouldn't be "slow" - though it's unavoidably slower than plain objects.

Edit: If you really want to make life difficult for yourself and everybody else using your code, you can update your `append` function to do the following:

```
MyCollection.prototype.append = function (item) {
    this.array.push(item);
    this[this.array.length - 1] = item;
};
```

Comment: I'm not using the `class` keyword, so it needs to use the classic syntax. Also, my collection should not have most of Array's methods. And proxies are much slower, they say.

Comment: I found one that suggested a performance that's 20 times slower. Does jQuery use a proxy for that? I thought proxies didn't even exist when jQuery was created.

Comment: Proxies aren't really that slow and are being using in lots of frameworks to detect changes and do things like re-rendering. Are they slower than plain objects, yes. Are they too slow for your app... I'd bet not. And you don't have to use the `class` keyword to inherit from Array - it's just prettier (look up prototypal inheritance for JS).

Comment: I've updated my answer with a possible solution... though "solution" is a bit of a misnomer. You are creating a severe headache for yourself, and if I was reviewing your code I would not allow what you are doing `</fifteen-years-of-experience>`.

Comment: Alright, so if I use a proxy for this, does it have to intercept *all* properties of my collection object or can I limit this to only the numeric properties? I've tried hooking things together with prototypes to first try the collection prototype's own methods and finally try the numeric indices through the proxy, but that hasn't worked so far because the proxy needs to be created for a specific instance. BTW, jQuery seems to explicitly create the numeric properties for its array-like interface. That's hardly manageable for a more advanced collection type.

Comment: Proxies *are* slow. I've measured the most basic implementation myself. It's 200 times slower, even a little more so in Chrome than in Firefox. So if I provide that array-like indexer interface, I'll really want to limit the code path through proxies to that part of the interface, not every other available method. Manually creating numeric properties is a lot faster than using a proxy (about the factor 5).

Comment: I mean - are you doing over 100,000 property reads/writes per second, if not, Proxy will not get in your way and it solves the problem you're after in a meaningful and semantic manner. You can proxy the actual prototype of your class instead of every instance. Here's a quick an dirty test runner to compare different approaches: https://jsfiddle.net/fyrb8d94/

Comment: But even tests like this don't highlight efficiencies in JS engines. For example, if you make the values in that test more random, then the performance is negligible. The only thing different in this fiddle is the instance values now have `Math.random()` in it, which means the JS engine cannot optimize it: https://jsfiddle.net/fyrb8d94/1/. So back to my 15 years of experience - don't try to worry too much about the performance of things like this. You're wasting your time and making life harder for yourself and other developers on your team.